# Load page from different domain and highlight/scroll to text section of that page

Tags: html, iframe, scroll, cross-domain, highlight

Is it possible to tell the browser to open a website from a different domain (e.g. in an iframe) and highlight part of its text and scroll that part into view? (Remember when Google offered cached versions of the search result pages in which the search results were highlighted?)

I would like to avoid having to proxy the page through a server and modifying it there. Is there a way to do this client-side? This would probably require cross-site-scripting, which will be difficult, correct?

There only needs to be one section in the text highlighted, so I don't really care whether this happens via a text-selection or whether some markup (like a span element) is placed around the section.

Unfortunately, which site this other page is from is beyond my control, so modifying that page to include an anchor at the right position won't be possible for me.

Is it for example possible to tell the browser to do a full-text-search in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid all the answers are already in your question. Client side, you cannot reach the content of a page from another domain not under your control. Cross-site techniques like postMessage will only work if you control both ends.